# Remove memcached completely from django

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached

Please tell some way to completely remove memcached from Django server. Using apache with mod WSGI and have already deleted all caches lines from settings.py but even that file is being cached.

Even removing settings.py doesn't stop site from working. This is ridiculous. There is no .pyc being formed which I could delete. Where are the files being cached.

I cannot get code changes in .py files to reflect in any way. They sometimes reflect, sometimes the old code comes back from some cache. How can I delete all caching mechanisms from this server ?

Regards !

Comment: Sounds like mod_wsgi is caching the Python files in memory; depending on the Apache worker your request is handled by you'll get to see old ('cached') responses. Does restarting Apache entirely solve your problem?

Comment: Nope. Restarting even the server physically solves it for a few minutes, it is absolutely unpredictable. Sometimes works, sometimes does not. Any way to clear these cached files from memory ?

Comment: restarting Apache will do.

Comment: Open the site in Incognito/Private Browsing mode to make sure it's not your browser that's caching things. And also make sure Apache isn't configure to cache anything with mod_cache or something similar.

Comment: In private browsing, results are the same. There is no file called mod_cache in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled

But you are right, python files are being cached somewhere. How to delete them is what am unable to figure out ! :(

Answer (score 0):

This isn't anything to do with memcache; it sounds like the old compiled python scripts are still being used. Theoretically, restarting apache should do it. If not, deleting all the .pyc files (compiled python files; not .py, which are your source code) and restarting your server should force it to regenerate the .pyc files from the current source.